# Removing random line from text file - Python

Tags: python, random

I've just set up a twitter bot. It pulls it tweets at random from a text file and tweets it. Becuase Twitter does not allow duplicate tweets, how can I delete the tweet from the text file so it doesn't try and tweet it again?
the relevant bits of code look like this:

```
while True:
 lines = open('tweets.txt').read().splitlines()
 tweet = random.choice(lines)
 twitter.update_status(status=tweet)
 print (tweet)
 sleepTime = random.randint(30, 60)
 time.sleep(sleepTime)
```

Edit:
I need the .txt file to update/save without the last tweet in it. So that it doesn't try and read it again.

Comment: Initialize `lines` only at the start, then remove entries from the list as you pick them.

Comment: @triplee, Thanks! could you give an example?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply remove this from list `lines` if you don't need this tweet anymore:

```
while True:
  lines = open('tweets.txt').read().splitlines()
  ...
  for line in lines:
     if line == tweet:
         lines.remove(line)

#EDIT this code write list 'lines' without removed line
with open("tweets.txt", 'w') as f:                                                                                                          
for l in lines:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    f.write(l + '\n')
```

Comment: that would've been real easy. But it won't update the .txt file that the bot reads the tweets from.

Comment: You sir/Ma'm are a genius, works just how I wanted.